# Euclidean norm vs pythagorean theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces, vectors

I recently stumbled upon an Euclidian norm. First I thought there are the powers and square root to deal with possible negative values (like in Standard deviation formula) but then I realized, the final number (sum of squares and square root of it) is not same as sum of absolute numbers.

So then I noticed it is more related to Pythagorean theorem (Euclidian distance).

But if looked in google for PT in 3d space i found the formula like

```
(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^1/2
```

http://www.math.brown.edu/tbanchof/Beyond3d/chapter8/section02.html

But in the Euclidian norm it is

```
SQRT(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)
```

How comes, it is different?

Second question, how comes that the theorem works for any count of dimensions?

Comment: `^1/2` is the same as `SQRT`.

Comment: @player3236 oh! aha, i didn't know that ok thanks. and how comes it works for any dimensions count? how to imagine the 4d space?

Comment: If you have $2$ vectors in a vector space, they span a 2d plane (or line if they are parallel), and you can apply/visualize orthogonality and Pythagorean theorem there. The key point is to understand the step from 2d to 3d in Pythagorean theorem, and it works just the same way in higher dimensions.

Comment: @Berci ok thank you

Answer (score 2):

The two formulas are indeed the same.

You can generalize it to $n$ dimensions by repeated application of Pythagoras:

$$\|(a,b,c)\|=\|(a,\|(b,c)\|)\|=\|(a,\sqrt{b^2+c^2})\|=\sqrt{a^2+(b^2+c^2)}$$ and so on.

(In this reasoning, you project $(a,b,c)$ to the plane $yz$, giving $(b,c)$ as an intermediate point, joining the origin to $(b,c)$, then $(b,c)$ to $(a,b,c)$.)